# Trouble updating Craft when allowAdminChanges is false

Tags: craft3, multi-environment, projectconfig, project.yaml

I've just updated a multi-environment site from Craft 3.3.5 to 3.4.5. Here's our config/general.php (irrelevant bits removed):

```
return [
    '*' => [
        'allowAdminChanges' => false,
        'allowUpdates' => false,
        'devMode' => false,
        'useProjectConfigFile' => true,
    ],
    'dev' => [
        'allowAdminChanges' => true,
        'allowUpdates' => true,
        'devMode' => true,
    ],
    'production' => [],
];
```

The update succeeded in the development environment (localhost) but the production deployment failed*. Here's the post-deployment command:

`/path/to/composer install --no-interaction --prefer-dist --optimize-autoloader && ~/user/craft project-config/sync`

When the deployment failed, I went to /admin and received the "Finish Up" button. I clicked it. I then received the "Sync" button and clicked it as well. I then received an error. Unfortunately I can't remember what the error said and didn't take a screenshot. It was a nicely-formatted error (not just a PHP dump) and there was a Troubleshoot link under it.*

Anyway, I SSH'd into the server and ran `project-config/sync` manually. Here's what was returned:

`Applying changes from project.yaml ... error: Changes to the project config are not possible while in read-only mode.`

I then edited config/general.php and made `allowAdminChanges` true on production. Reloading /admin worked and I was able to log into Craft.

**At long last, here's my question**:

We're following the advice per the [allowAdminChanges docs](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/config/config-settings.html#allowadminchanges). Does this advice only apply to non-update changes? In other words, is it a known thing that `allowAdminChanges` must be true when pushing a change to project.yaml that will update Craft?

--

*FWIW, we do have a staging deployment but it doesn't apply to this question.

--

**EDIT**: I ran another test, here's the error:

```
A fatal error has occurred:

Status: Internal Server Error
Response: {"error":"A server error occurred."}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think P&T changed the behavior in Craft 3.1.0 and newer. Before 3.1.0 it was necessary to have `'allowAdminChanges' => true` with updates in/to project config.

To be 100% safe you can always enable admin changes when you're on the command line by using this config line in production environments:

```
'allowAdminChanges' => (php_sapi_name() === 'cli'),
```

In most installations we even go step further and have a second domain available, which also enables admin changes when this domain is used (for emergencies), where *www.yourdomain.com* would be the normal domain and *admin.yourdomain.com* could be the one with admin changes enabled:

```
'allowAdminChanges' => (php_sapi_name() === 'cli' || strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], 'admin.') !== false),
```